# Hiding an image until the document is loaded, then applying effects to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to find a simple, but bulletproof way of hiding an image until it's loaded, and then giving it some jQuery effects (e.g. `fadeIn`) but all the methods I've found seem to have some issues. For example, this solution:

```
<img id="photo" src="bigimage.jpg" style="display:none" />

$("#photo").load(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

May not trigger if the image is loaded before the DOM is ready (`load()` won't fire).

So I wrote the following, which only adds the URL once the image has definitely loaded...

```
$.fn.ImageLoad = function(url){
        $image = $(this);
        $("<img >").attr("src", url).load(function(){ 
            $image.attr("src", url);
        });
        return $image;
}; 

$("#cast").ImageLoad("http://pas-wordpress-media.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Google-Office-Building-in-NYC.jpg").fadeIn("slow");
```

But it only runs the `fadeIn("slow")` once the image has been cached by the browser. The first time it loads, it just appears with no effects.

**See your yourself here:** http://jsfiddle.net/KKn4N/

Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version. Works every single time and completely cross browser.

```
$.fn.ImageLoad = function(url){
    $this = $(this);
    $this.hide().on('load', function(){
        $this.fadeIn();
    });
    this[0].src = url;
};
```

The key is to

- do the fade inside a callback
- hide first
- listen for the `.load` before you set the `.src`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6BZZQ/)**

Comment: I can't say I understand it... (how does it know what to `.load`?? but it does appear to work as intended! Thank you! :)

Comment: So `.load` is an overloaded method. In other words it does more than one thing, (not good api design imho). `.load` can either 1. load content from a server, OR 2. listen for an `onload` event kind of like `.click`. Updating my answer to be more clear.

Comment: I see you've changed the code now. Was this for clarity purposes? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, just for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get it correctly - I'm assuming you mean hide all images when page loads until all images are loaded and then fade them in?
If so, then why not just set display:none on images (maybe give them a class `.hidden {display:none}`)  and then wait for window load event (i.e. all loaded) and trigger fade on all images - they will then nicely all fade in at the same time.

```
$('img.hidden').fadeIn('slow');
```

Example:

## html

```
<img class=hidden src=http://cdn-4.lifehack.org/wp-content/files/2013/09/javascript-logo.png></img>
```

## css

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

## js

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('img.hidden').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: Quite aggressive, as it will wait for 'total' page load before showing images. This is not a good practice, as things like server timeouts on specific resources, or browser plugins can delay the `window.onload` event for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, load the image first, then attach the fadeIn afterwards.

```
    $.fn.ImageLoad = function(url){
        $image = $(this);
        $("<img >").attr("src", url).load(function(){ 
            $image.attr("src", url);
        });
        return $image;
}; 

$("#cast").ImageLoad("http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ff_googleinfrastructure_large.jpg");
$("#cast").fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: This wont work because the .fadeIn will fire before the async loading process is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jU97F/)

```
<img 
  id="cast" 
  style="display:none" 
  src="http://pas-wordpress-media.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Google-Office-Building-in-NYC.jpg" 
  onload="$(document).ready(function(){$('#cast').fadeIn('slow')})"
/>
```

Comment: This will work, but using inline javascript is a very bad practice. Also there is no need for `.ready` as load will always complete after ready.